# Generated PersonController expects Authority to contain word ROLE

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm brand new to acegi and relatively new to Grails.

I just followed the tutorial to set up a new role and a new user.   Every time I saved the user (with a role checked), it saved the user information fine, but not the role associated with the user.

I finally dug into the controller code that was generated, and noticed this:

```
private void addRoles(person) {
    for (String key in params.keySet()) {
        if (key.contains('ROLE') && 'on' == params.get(key)) {
            Authority.findByAuthority(key).addToPeople(person)
        }
    }
}
```

So to be sure I was interpreting it correctly, I added the word ROLE to my authorties, and it worked like a charm.   Am I missing something obvious, is this a bug, or.......?

The examples showed simple role names like "user" or "manager".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your Acegi authorities should be ROLE_something.
It is possible to change the default prefix configuration from ROLE_ to something else: http://www.acegisecurity.org/acegi-security/apidocs/org/acegisecurity/runas/RunAsManagerImpl.html